# ckeditor 4.13 how to disable content transformation

Tags: ckeditor

when I paste stuff from word to ckeditor(my version is 4.13.0) - it is pain in the ass how to set the right configuration.

I know that a lot of spans are coming from word so I try to escape them by changing text colors and text formats to 'font' instead like this

```
//default for font and color are span but change to font because need to escape span when paste from word
config.fontSize_style = {
    element:        'font',
    styles:         { 'font-size': '#(size)' },
    overrides:      [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': null } } ]
};


config.font_style = {
    element:        'font',
    styles:         { 'font-family': '#(family)' },
    overrides:      [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'face': null } } ]
};

config.colorButton_foreStyle = {
    element: 'font',
    attributes: { 'color': '#(color)' }
};

config.colorButton_backStyle = {
    element: 'font',
    styles: { 'background-color': '#(color)' }
};
```

but I still need span for specific class like

```
config.allowedContent =
                            'h1 h2 h3 h4 strong u strike sub sup blockquote em ul ol li p ;table[*]{*}(*);font[*]{*}(*);s[*]{*}(*); td[*]{*}(*); th[*]{*}(*); tr[*]{*}(*);' +
                            'a[!href,target,class,onclick,id](*);' +
                            'img[!src,alt,width,height];' +
                            'span[!class](update,textnote,andy,footnote);' +
                            'div[*]{margin-left,margin-right,text-align}(*);'

                            ;
```

but when I copy and paste some stuff ckeditor tranforms

```
<span style="background-color:white>
```

into `<font style="background-color:white>`

I definitely don't want that - how can I disable it when paste from word?
I tried set config.pastefilter differently but nothing works!!